# Configure Nginx - Create vhost file

Tags: django, nginx, server, vhosts

I am falowing this tutorial:
[Setting up Django, Nginx, MySQL and uWSGI](http://www.krishnasunuwar.com.np/2014/12/setting-up-django-nginx-mysql-and-uwsgi/)

And my server at this point is working, when I go to the IP of my server, I can see the "It worked!" django's page.

But right now I am at:

> Part 3: Configuration of Nginx and uWSGI
>
> Configure Nginx
>
> 1) Create vhost file /etc/nginx/site-available

I realy don't know how to do this, What is and how to create a vhost file? Where? Why? What for?, Should it have an special name?

Of course I already made a research, but I only found bigger configurations and even terminal command's that make me feel more lost.

Or if you konw a better tutorial, I will apreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: That's not a very good tutorial - apart from anything else it should be "site**s**-available" - but it does tell you exactly what to put in your file *immediately* after the line you quote, so I don't see what is confusing you.

Answer (score 0):

vhost file can have anyname.

Then you have to put server blocks in the file.

Finally run
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

and then restart nginx service

[You can follow this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-14-04)